# MySQL: Constraint two columns so one of them always are NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with references from two of it's columns to two other tables PK's. Is there a way I can restrict both of those columns from having values set?

I only want one of them to have a value set, while the other is NULL

**Favorites:**

```
id
table_1_id
table_2_id
```

**Table_1:**

```
id
```

**Table_2:**

```
id
```

Comment: You could emulate a check constraint with a trigger: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints

Comment: Is table_1.id related in any way to Table_2.id? If so, you have an exclusive arc, a database antipattern that will cause you no end of problems. Please describe what Table_1 and Table_2 represent, and explain what your end goal is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL, you'd ideally handle this with a [CHECK constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp).

In MySQL, there is not a direct mechanism to impose such a CHECK constraint. If you try to include one, the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.htmlhttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) states (since it's part of the standard):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: That means I'll have to resort to a update trigger mechanism ? In my case that would not work...

Comment: Maybe your application could handle it by using a transaction? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Is there a smart reason for not implementing the check constraint on MySQL like (performance , speed , scalability … )  or juste developers didn't get payed enough to add that ?