# MySQL: Constraining a set of columns so at least one is not NULL

Tags: mysql, constraints

I want to have a SQL table with two columns.  One is a key into another table, the other holds a string literal.  The idea is phone numbers can be entered either exactly (in which case the ID into the phonebook table is used) or as a wildcard (in which the string literal is used).

This means that one column in the table will hold a value, and the other will hold a NULL.

Is it possible to constrain a table in such a way that one column must have a value, and the other must be NULL?  If both columns are NULL or both have a value, then the row is invalid.

I have a feeling that MySQL can't do this (as it doesn't seem to have a comprehensive toolbox when it comes to constraints), but it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: This may help (not *exactly* the same though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523351/mysql-constraint-two-columns-so-one-of-them-always-are-null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to enforce such a constraint.

As a workaround, you may consider to have two different columns: If you have one column for the data - containing the phonebook id or the string literal, and another column for the data type - either 'exact' or 'wildcard' -, you can set a NOT NULL constraint to both columns. One obvious drawback is that you cannot have a FK constraint to the phonebooks table any more.

Comment: I'm going to accept this, but the actual design I went for is somewhat different.  I instead added a Kind field that can be either exact or wildcard, and the content of the Key field will point either to the phonebook, or a new wildcard table, depending on the value of the kind field.  The kind and key are a composite unique key, so the key can can contain the same value twice (once for a key to the phone book, and once for a key to the wildcards).

Answer (score 6):

Ever since `GENERATED` columns are a thing, this is possible.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_multiple_not_null` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `idOne` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idTwo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `not_null_constrain` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(`idOne`,`idTwo`)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Since every time a row is inserted, the generated column must run to see it if satisfies `NOT NULL` constrain it will reply with `1048: Column 'not_null_constrain' cannot be null`, if it would violate this restriction.

Answer (score 2):

You can make triggers to run on before the insert, to check the values and determine if the insert or update should happen or not. A good example for how to create triggers like this can be found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43284/two-nullable-columns-one-required-to-have-value

Answer (score 0):

The following triggers worked for me:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_OrgFeeOwnerInsert
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON OrganisationFee
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT ((new.fieldA IS NULL) + (new.fieldB IS NULL) + (new.fieldC IS NULL)) <> 2)
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'my error message';
    END IF;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER tgr_OrgFeeOwnerUpdate
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON OrganisationFee
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT ((new.fieldA IS NULL) + (new.fieldB IS NULL) + (new.fieldC IS NULL)) <> 2)
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'my error message';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Should the second trigger be `BEFORE UPDATE`? The two triggers look the same to me, besides the assigned name.